# CDN & Heroku: Background images doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cdn

In my Heroku rails app. I follow this instruction and implemented CDN. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31#configuration

It is almost working correctly, but the background image I wrote in css.scss.erb file doesn't show up.
My files and the problem are below.

## custom.css.scss.erb

```
.ap-sidebar .ap-nav li a span { 
   background: transparent url(asset-path('nav_arrows.png', image)) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

## staging.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

The output url should be:
staging-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/nav_arrows-digest.png

but the indeed output is like below:
.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/nav_arrows-digest.png

I changed asset-path to asset-url, but it didn't work.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should check:

- The environment variable ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] may be nil. You can check the env variables with the command:

  heroku config --app

More details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

- The mode of your app running on Heroku. By default, your app will run in production mode, while you're configuring for staging mode. You can change the mode by following this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Comment: ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] is working for other images. Only the background image I wrote inside CSS file doesn't show up.

Comment: Did you try background: transparent url("<%= asset_path('nav_arrows.png') %>") ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this.

just change this:

```
.ap-sidebar .ap-nav li a span { 
   background: transparent url(asset-path('nav_arrows.png', image)) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

to this:

```
.ap-sidebar .ap-nav li a span { 
   background: transparent url('nav_arrows.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

css.scss.erb is not working, so I also omit erb from the file.